# Toast message is not shown while using progressive dialog box

Tags: android

here is my code for sending a mail enquiry using custom mail function,The problem is when i apply progressive dialog when sending mail the toast message  "Your enquiry has been sent to our team." is shown and after that "There was a problem sending the enquiry." toast is also showing but mail is properly sent.
Please help me to solve this issue.

**JAVA**

```
/      dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProjectEnquiry.this, "", 
                       //     "Sending enquiry...", true);
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProjectEnquiry.this, "Please wait ...",  "Task in progress ...", true);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            String msgbody="Name :  "+name.getText().toString()+"\n\nMobile Number :  "+mobile.getText().toString()+"\n\nProject Name:  "+s1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n\nType of apartment:  "+s2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n";
                            Mail m = new Mail("munnasuriya@gmail.com", "qafhsanib"); 
                            String[] toArr = {"ashfaqbinnazar@yahoo.com"}; 
                            //m.send()
                            m.setTo(toArr); 
                            m.setFrom("munnasuriya@gmail.com"); 
                            m.setSubject("Project Enquiry(Android Application)"); 
                            m.setBody(msgbody); 
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "okkk setting.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            try { 
                           //   m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

                              if(m.send()) { 

                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your enquiry has been sent to our team.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                      }
                                  });
                                  //Intent intent= new Intent(ProjectEnquiry.this, MainActivity.class); 
                                  //startActivity(intent);
                                  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        ProjectEnquiry.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProjectEnquiry.this,MainActivity.class));

                                    }
                                }, 3000);

                              } else { 

                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                          Toast.makeText(ProjectEnquiry.this, "Your enquiry was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                      }
                                  });
                              } 
                            } catch(Exception e) { 

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(ProjectEnquiry.this, "There was a problem sending the enquiry.",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                  }
                              });
                            }   

                            Thread.sleep(3000); // Let's wait for some time
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: if your class extends Activity class then use ClassName.this in place of getApplicationContext(). or use getActivity() or getApplication()

Comment: Condition is true and code works perfectly but the toast message after dialogue box is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this if code part:

```
 if(m.send()) { 

                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your enquiry has been sent to our team.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                          }
                                      });
                                      //Intent intent= new Intent(ProjectEnquiry.this, MainActivity.class); 
                                      //startActivity(intent);
                                      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            ProjectEnquiry.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProjectEnquiry.this,MainActivity.class));

                                        }
                                    }, 3000);

                                  }
```

to this:

```
if(m.send()) { 

                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your enquiry has been sent to our team.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                                  //Intent intent= new Intent(ProjectEnquiry.this, MainActivity.class); 
                                  //startActivity(intent);

                                        ProjectEnquiry.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProjectEnquiry.this,MainActivity.class));

                                    }
                                  });

                              }
```

If you have any problem, Please let me know.

Comment: Dear Vivek,
Thanks alot for your kind help.
Its working perfectly :)
Let me ask you one more thing?
Im using custom mail function for sending mail you can see my mail body in the above code,Can i add html in that body to see the mail in a html style/table layout?

Comment: Let me ask you one more thing? Im using custom mail function for sending mail you can see my mail body in the above code,Can i add html in that body to see the mail in a html style/table layout?

Comment: i never tried this.. You can explore more on this. Thanks.